# Replace a tag with href link

Tags: php, regex

I have a html source code and want to replace **all** `<a>` tags with its containing href link.

So the tag looks like:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

I expect as output:

```
http://google.com
```

I already tried some regex in combination with preg_replace, 
but none of them give me the href content.

So what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match with regex `<a .*href="([^"]*)".*?<\/a>` and replace with first group using `\1` or `$1`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB2tG5/1)**

Comment: This solution only matches the last occurance of an because of the .* before href. Copy and paste the Test string in the regex101 demo. 
A Solution for me is:

<a [^href]*href="([^"]*)".*?<\/a>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = '
  Random text <a href="foobar.html">Foobar</a> More Text
  Other text <a href="http://www.example.com">An example</a>
  Still more text <a href="http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html">A deep link</a>. The end.
';

preg_match_all('/<a href="(.*?)"/i',$text,$matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    print "A link: $match\n";
}
```

The result:

```
A link: foobar.html
A link: http://www.example.com
A link: http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html
```

Comment: This won't completely match till end of `<a>` tag.

Comment: It doesn't need to.  The non-greedy search `(.*?)"`will stop the match when it hits the closing quotation marks.

Comment: But it has to **replace** hole `<a>` tag. 

P.S: No down votes from me. Someone is trying to earn his `suffrage` badge. :D

Comment: Ah, he's replacing, not just matching.  In that case my regex would probably be similar to yours.  `$text = preg_replace('#<a href="(.*?)".*?</a>#i', "$1", $text);`